# Select FirstOrDefault Value Bind to Gridview Window Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to bind the top 1 value from my SQL database table to a `GridView`, but it's not displaying:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WireLine_Tracking_AssetsDataContext doc = new WireLine_Tracking_AssetsDataContext();

    if (txtCustomerInvoiceNo.Text != string.Empty )
    {
        var query = (from b in doc.WireLine_Movements 
                     where b.CustomerInvoiceNo.Contains(txtCustomerInvoiceNo.Text.Trim())
                     orderby b.ID descending
                     select new { b.AssetCode, b.CustomerInvoiceNo, b.CurrentLocation,
                                  b.FromLocation}).FirstOrDefault();
        dgvresult.DataSource = query;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged to check there is actually a first result, or if it's "default"?

Comment: have you checked if the `query` is not null?

Comment: @KingKing `query` can never be null. It can be empty

Comment: Ah, am sorry I missed `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: @Grant Winney In that case, replacing `FirstOrDefault` with `Take(1)` ought to help. Disappointing that there's no exception, then.

Comment: I have debugged and observe query value in the immediate window i can see the result but only in griedview i do see the result. Below is immediate window result

query
{ AssetCode = "OSU-PA", CustomerInvoiceNo = "test1", CurrentLocation = null, FromLocation = "UGDA" }
    AssetCode: "OSU-PA"
    CurrentLocation: null
    CustomerInvoiceNo: "test1"
    FromLocation: "UGDA"

Comment: You should use `Take(1)` instead, `GrantWinney` had a good point on the problem, in fact the `DataSource` of a `DataGridView` should implement `IList` or `IBindingList`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with below

```
var query = (from b in doc.WireLine_Movements 
                     where b.CustomerInvoiceNo.Contains(txtCustomerInvoiceNo.Text.Trim())
                     orderby b.ID descending
                     select new { b.AssetCode, b.CustomerInvoiceNo, b.CurrentLocation,
                                  b.FromLocation}).Take(1).ToList();
```

You can't Bind one item to grid view. create list from the item and set it as datasourse

Comment: `FormView` is not `winforms stuff`, so it can't be what the OP needs for his solution, if the OP wants to display 1 single item in a `DataGridView`, he can just add that single item to a `List` and use the `List` as the DataSource like this `.DataSource = new List<object>{singleItem};`